# FIXT1.1 ERROR_MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER PartyRole

Tags: fix-protocol

**New Order Single(D)**

Request-

```
FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, outgoing> (8=FIXT.1.19=14635=D34=449=SendercompId52=20191226-05:19:22.66156=TargetCompId11=157733756231838=10040=154=155=2GO59=060=20191226-13:19:22.645447=I448=135452=3453=010=253)
```

Response-

```
FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, incoming> (8=FIXT.1.19=00020535=849=SendercompId56=TargetCompId34=452=20191226-05:19:22.73537=NONE11=157733756231817=TE5368150=839=8103=9955=2GO54=138=10040=1151=014=060=20191226-05:19:22.73158=ERROR.MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER PartyRole10=240)
```

> ERROR.MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER PartyRole

Kindly suggest with a proper example which gives correct response for **New Order Single(D)**
Kindly gives actual values related to parties

```
quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle newOrderSingle = new quickfix.fix50sp1.NewOrderSingle(new ClOrdID(order.getID()),
                sideToFIXSide(order.getSide()), new TransactTime(), typeToFIXType(order.getType()));
         newOrderSingle.setField(new NoPartyIDs(?));
         newOrderSingle.setField(new PartyRole(?));
         newOrderSingle.setField(new PartyIDSource('?'));
         newOrderSingle.setField(new PartyID("?"));

 - List item
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: When working with FIX protocol, as a first step make your logging replace non-printable ASCII `0x01` with `|`. It will make reading FIX messages much nicer.

Comment: We are sending all the required tag which is read from the FIX documents but still this error are coming 58=ERROR.MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER PartyRole Please tell me which tag i am missing and what value have to send that tag

Answer (score 2):

Fundamental part of the FIX protocol is the FIX dictionary, which is part of *Rules of Engagement (RoE)* between your system and the *Execution Venue* (aka *Broker* or *Counterparty*). It specifies what messages are part of the protocol and what fields are required on specific messages in specific scenarios, specifically, what fields are required on the `New Order Single` (`35=D`) message.

In your case, the text (tag `58`) of the reject message, `Execution Report` (`35=9|39=8`) indicates that your application is not sending a mandatory tag `PartyRole (452)` on the request: `58=ERROR.MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER PartyRole`. But there will be more of them and you should really start from reading the Broker's ROE.

If you are just playing with FIX and coding both ends of the session yourself, check what fields are in use in the [QuickFIXj Examples](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/tree/master/quickfixj-examples) or in examples in my [FIXGlue](https://github.com/mrbald/fixglue) repository. It should get you going.

Comment: We are sending all the required tag which is read from the FIX documents but still this error are coming 58=ERROR.MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER PartyRole Please tell me which tag i am missing and what value have to send that tag

Comment: @Farhana Khan: unfortunately, it is common for an execution venue's documentation to contain mistakes, such as neglecting to list some fields. I suggest you contact the technical support of the execution venue. If you send them a sample FIX message and the error you received, then they should be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Can you please provide me any example which can resolve this error?
i have applied this same example https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/tree/master/quickfixj-examples but still error is coming.
Please help me with example if possible.

Comment: Here is a list of PartyRoles. Maybe you are able to find the correct one on your own. ;) https://btobits.com/fixopaedia/fixdic50-sp2-ep/tag_452_PartyRole_.html