# Request send on test PSE for *New Order Single (D) *

Tags: java, fix-protocol

How can you send the **new order single** request on test PSE.
I made my request according to FIX official documents but still, error is coming-

**Request-**

> 8=FIXT.1.19=15335=D34=349=13552=20191226-04:40:18.78856=PSE11=157733521842938=10040=144=9.8154=155=2GO59=060=20191226-12:40:18.772447=D448=0452=36453=010=062

**Response-**

> 8=FIXT.1.19=21335=834=349=PSE52=20191226-04:40:18.86056=13511=157733521842914=017=TE536337=NONE38=10039=840=144=9.8154=155=2GO58=ERROR.MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER
>   PartyRole60=20191226-04:40:18.856103=99150=8151=010=209

**Please help and suggest me how can I send my request on test PSE and get a proper response.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FIXT1.1 ERROR\_MISSING\_EXECUTINGTRADER PartyRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484651/fixt1-1-error-missing-executingtrader-partyrole)

Comment: You have asked the very same question and got valuable answers before. Maybe you should ask PSE, whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not a generic FIX protocol issue, but a logical error that stems from you not following your counterparty's proper procedure.

Do you see this field?  `58=ERROR.MISSING_EXECUTINGTRADER`

You have sent them New Order Single message that is clearly missing information that they want.

You need to get ahold of your counterparty's documentation for this FIX interface and read it thoroughly.

Comment: where i can get this ** counterparty's documentation** ?

Comment: Your counterparty is whoever you are connecting to.  The are the guys who own whatever "test PSE" is.